# Добавление символа

Tags: vb.net

Доброе время суток.
Имеются числа

560

590

132560

9568

Необходимо вставить знак "." перед вторым символом слева:

5.60

5.90

1325.60

95.68

Comment: `number = number / 100`.

Comment: А если это будет потом текст?

Comment: Функция CStr()...